# What does $z\in(-1,1)$ mean?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am solving a question where it is given that $z\in(-1,1)$.
But what does this mean?
As z is depending on two variables (x and y) and not on one variable.

Comment: More context would help... Usually $(-1,1)$ means the open interval on the *real* line.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that $z=x+iy$ is a complex number. Then, the condition $z\in(-1,1)$ would mean that the complex number happens to lie along the interval $(-1,1)\subset\mathbb R$, or in other words $y=0$ and $-1<x<1$.